# Select max of one date after getting max of other date

Tags: date, max

I am using Oracle's PSQuery tool so I do not have access to the actual code. I would like to generate a list of students with their maximum dropped course . However, if the student has more than one dropped course on the same max date, I want to return the one with the max deadline date. So, all max drop dates with duplicates narrowed down further by max deadline date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.studentid, s.name, MAX(s.date), (s.deadlineDate), MAX(d.droppedCourse) AS droppedCourse
  FROM Student s
  JOIN DeadlineDate d ON s.studentid = d.studentid
  GROUP BY s.studentid, s.name, s.date
  HAVING MAX(d.DeadlineDate);
```